# F is differentiable and satisfies this inequality, prove that its partial derivatives do exist and that they are continous

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^N \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that for all $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^N$ and $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that if $a, b, c, d \in B(x_0, \delta)$ with $a \neq b$ and $c \neq d$, then it follows that:
$
\left|\frac{f(a)-f(b)}{\|a-b\|}-\frac{f(c)-f(d)}{\|c-d\|}\right| < \epsilon.
$

(a) Prove that the partial derivatives of $f$ exist.

(b) Now prove that they are continuous.

My attempt:

The first idea I have is to choose $a, b, c,$ and $d$ in a way that allows us to break down the inequality into a definition I already know. Let's review the inequality again:

$$
\left|\frac{{f(a) - f(b)}}{{\|a - b\|}} - \frac{{f(c) - f(d)}}{{\|c - d\|}}\right| < \epsilon.
$$

Now, let $\mathbf{e}_j$ be a unit vector belonging to $\mathbb{R}^N$. Let $h$ be small enough so that $(x_0 + h\mathbf{e}_j)$ belongs to $B(x_0, \delta)$. We can then do the following:

$
a = x_0 + h\mathbf{e}_j, \quad b = x_0, \quad c = x_0 - h\mathbf{e}_j, \quad d = x_0.
$

Let's substitute these values into the inequality:

$
\left|\frac{{f(x_0 + h\mathbf{e}_j) - f(x_0)}}{{\|h\mathbf{e}_j\|}} - \frac{{f(x_0 - h\mathbf{e}_j) - f(x_0)}}{{\|h\mathbf{e}_j\|}}\right| < \epsilon.
$

Now, I have the definition of partial derivatives on the left side approaching from the "right side" (thanks to $+h$) and the definition of partial derivatives on the right side approaching from the "left side" ($-h$). My idea is that as $h$ approaches 0, the partial derivative actually exists and is zero since this holds for every $\epsilon$. I am also considering using this as a way to state that the partial derivative is continuous.

my proof is ok? i did something wrong? can i do something better? Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I suspect that you first need to produce a candidate for the partials, and then show convergence in general. Perhaps take $b=d=x_0$ and $a=x_0+{1 \over n} e_k$, $b=x_0+{1 \over m} e_k$ and show that the sequence ${f(x_0+{1 \over n} e_k) - f(x_0) \over {1 \over n}}$ is Cauchy.

Comment: candidate for the partials? well, if you take 1/n and 1/m small enough then you will have the cauchy inequality almost inmediatly. ok, so I guess that what we are trying to prove is that, since (1/n) is a cauchy sequence, we can say that ${f(x_0+{1 \over n} e_k) - f(x_0) \over {1 \over n}}$ is cauchy continous. and then the partial derivatives do exist because of the continuity of ${f(x_0+{1 \over n} e_k) - f(x_0) \over {1 \over n}}$. i am on the right track?

Comment: ok, i was finally able to solve a) using the right values for a,b,c and d. Now, is my response to copper.hat good enough to prove b) aka that the partial derivatives are continous?

Comment: Continuity follows from the formula once you establish that the partials exist.